# Photo Resistor to Complete Circuit in Light

Tags: ldr, photoresistor

I am trying to create a very simple circuit using a CDS photo resistor.  The situation is simple, I need a circuit to be connected when its light, disconnected when its dark.  The photocell will sit in complete darkness, when a camera flash is fired, I want the photocell to simply connect a circuit which will then trigger other flashes.  The flash circuit doesn't carry any voltage, it just needs to be completed.  Basically, I need the two photocell to simply connect two wires when its light and disconnect them when its dark.

I am using this CDS photo cell: https://www.creatroninc.com/product/7mm-light-dependent-resistor-photo-resistor/?search_query=light+sensor&results=60

This is my first experience with one of theses Photo Resistors LDR and I thought it would be really simply but I'm striking out this morning.  Thank you!

Comment: That thing is probably too slow for what you want. I think you need a photo-diode .

Comment: Yeah, you want a photodiode. CdS (the d isn't capitalized, by the way) photocells are very slow and are, in just about every way, completely obsolete.

Comment: Ok, so if I pick up one of these: [link](https://www.creatroninc.com/product/bpw34-photodiode-430-to-1100nm/?search_query=photo+diode&results=20) how would I then put together the circuit?

Comment: CdS work fine in WeinBridge oscillators.

Answer (score 3):

As others have correctly said, a photo-diode would be the right part.

You can try something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzF2Yj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You need to choose a suitable opto-isolator for your trigger output requirements. That needs a comparator with a suitable output drive for it. As I don't know your trigger output requirements, I've left those.

The pot' adjusts the current at the trip point between 10 uA and 2 mA or thereabouts.

Answer (score 1):

The cadmium sulfide photocell is too slow to trigger on a camera flash. But if it *was* fast enough, this is how you would do it: use the photocell as one leg of a Wheatstone bridge, then use a comparator to switch some variety of voltage-controlled switch (e.g. relay, FET, analog mux, etc) based on the photocell's resistance. Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUxzRi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The values of R1 and R2 (specifically, R2/(R1+R2)) determine the sensitivity of the detector. You can put a potentiometer in there if you want to be able to set the light level at which it trips.

Comment: Yup, Relay may be a bit slow for photographic work though.

Comment: The CdS cell is too slow alone, I'd imagine. This is just intended to show the principle of how you would make a light level sensor.